# Conditional sum of a column according to the value of another column when grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to sum PONDERA when ESTADO==1 and then group by AGLOMERADO

```
new <- recorte %>% group_by(AGLOMERADO) %>%
                        summarise(TOTocupied=sum(recorte[recorte$ESTADO==1,"PONDERA"]))
```

The sum is working correctly, but I can't get the result to be grouped by AGLOMERADO, it gives me back the same result for each AGLOMERADO:

```
AGLOMERADO  TOTocupied
1           100
2           100
3           100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipe. Also no need to refer to the dataframe again since we are using pipes.

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

new <- recorte %>% 
         group_by(AGLOMERADO)%>%
         summarise(TOTocupied = sum(PONDERA[ESTADO==1], na.rm = TRUE))
```